# Start numbered list from sub point in word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a style that applies to numbered headings, e.g.

1 MY STYLE ITEM 1

...some text...

2 MY STYLE ITEM 2

...some text...

I want to change the style's numbering such that the first number is 33.2.3, and then have items iterate on the last digit, e.g.;

32.2.3 MY STYLE ITEM 1

...some text...

32.2.4 MY STYLE ITEM 2

...some text...

To achieve this I do the following:

Right Click on style -> Modify -> Format -> Numbering -> Define new number format and enter the format 1.1.1.

I then right click on this first item in my list and do the following:

Numbering -> Set Numbering Value -> Start new list -> Set value to

But here is where I hit the issue. I can only change the first value, when I wish to change all three.

What is the error in my approach?

Comment: Why don't you enter the format "32.2.1" instead of "1.1.1". Also take care the original value with grey background, that should be at the position you which to auto-update

Comment: I can do but that leaves me with the same issue, i.e. I would have 32.2.1, 33.2.1, 34.2.1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I poropose to use styles and multi-level list. On home tab, in paragraph group. In this way, all paragraphs styled, lets say `MyListLevel3` will be associated with this list, and all changes made there will be applied to all instances. If you are using default style for lists, it's behaving like `normal` style for paragraphs.